# Creating Scale-to-fit MDI applications - where to start?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, mdi

This is more of a 'where to start' kind of question and less of a 'how do I fix this thing I broke' question.

My company has an old Delphi 7 MDI application that we are porting to Delphi XE2 and my manager has asked me to look into methods by which we could make the application re-size to fit different monitor resolutions (it is currently forced to 1024*768 - yes, it is THAT old).

Although I have an idea of placing each component, with its dimensions and layout co-ords, in an array for each base resolution, and then multiplying these values by a ratio difference to achieve this 'scale to fit' issue, I am wondering if this is the most efficient method to achieve what we are seeking?

The MDI application, and it's children, only need to go to a bordered full screen, and then minimized, there will be no handling for a partially re-sized screen.

Anyway, hoping someone out there has run into a similar 'problem' and can point me in the right direction for articles/examples that explore various techniques for a 'scale to fit' MDI application.

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use the Anchors property?

Comment: There is built in DPI related mechanics which solves similar problem.

Comment: David, anchors are not something I have ever really played with, so I'll give that a go, thanks!